# EF6 for MySql InvalidOperationException

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6

This seems to be a common error but none of the fixes I have seen yet have worked.  I have two VS2015 EF6 "code first from database" solutions on my PC which have identical models and app.config files.  They both access the same database.  One runs, and the other throws this exception.

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6'
>   registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider
>   with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make
>   sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is
>   available to the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

The exception is thrown from `public virtual IList<NamedDbProviderService> DbProviderServices`

It seems that copying a working solution from one PC to another provokes this exception as does checking out the solution file from Git.  The only thing I can think of is that there is something wrong with the NuGet package restoration but deleting or uninstalling the packages or the package config and manually replacing them does not fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the EF driver for MySql is not loading when the config is parsed. Adding the following code to the main program fixes it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Force the MySql.Data.Entity Assembly to be loaded
    /// or the app.config file will not load 
    /// No need to call this function
    /// </summary>
    public static void Fix()
    {
        var name = MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName;
    }
```